# Django how to link a button to http response

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a simple page which requires a login and has a button which on clicking would download a csv file.

The code below works well, but this directly downloads the file.

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def index(request):

  response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.csv"'

  writer = csv.writer(response)
  writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
  writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

  return response
```

I can create a button and link view to it's template, but how do I return the above response from it.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
 <input type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with "directly downloading the file". How is what you want different?

Comment: If the link is visited file won't be downloaded, only clicking on the button would download it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate view that returns the csv file, and set your form to direct its submit to that view:

```
<form action="{% url 'my_csv_view' %} method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

In this case, your csv file would be served by the view named 'my_csv_view', but you can change that to something that suits you better.